# IMAP Proxy to allow an internal server to access emails via imap.gmail.com with dovecot

Tags: email, proxy, imap, dovecot

I need to find a way to set up dovecot as a mail proxy server which is internet facing to allow the internal server to access emails from gmail

not really good with dovecot so would be appreciate it if someone tell me how to configure as well thanks
so:

Imap.gmail.com => dovecot proxy => internal server (accessing email)

thanks in advance

Comment: The [Dovecot documentation](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields/Proxy) shows the way.

Comment: I did look at it before but I dot seem to understand it. Anyways to find a tutorial or a step by step walkthrough